# Automatic scroll to bottom using autolayout cells in a UiCollectionView

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, uicollectionview, swift4

I'm writing a chat part of an app i'm working on. The chat consists of cells that uses autoLayout for size. I haven't managed to get `ScrollToItem` to work, and a colleague of mine said that `ScrollToItem` doesn't work if the cells are set with auto layout.
I have read through other stackoverflow questions similar to mine, with no luck.

I'm aware that this has been discussed before (example in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14760496/uicollectionview-automatically-scroll-to-bottom-when-screen-loads)) but it doesn't take in consideration that i'm using `autoLayout`.

#### My main problem

I want the view to be scrolled to the bottom as soon as i have my data from
`Firebase Firestore`. Also as soon as someone taps the `UITextField`.

Any ideas on how this could be achieved?

#### My tests so far

```
func scrollToBottom(animated: Bool) {
    if self.messages.count > 0 {
        self.collectionView?.scrollToItem(at: IndexPath(item: self.messages.count - 1, section: 0), at: .bottom, animated: animated)
    }
}
```

Another solution was to flip the `view` upside down and also flipped it horizontally, and then flipped the cells back to it's original state. Is this a good solution?

Comment: It's the thread the author posted in his question @ShamasS

Comment: wow, how blind am I. I guess speed reading doesn't work for everyone. I've retracted the duplicate. My apologies.

Comment: >`flip the view upside down and then flipped the cells back to it's original state`. 
I think yes, because Telegram use this hack and it work perfectly
If you interesting how Telegram do this check [ViewController](https://github.com/peter-iakovlev/Telegram/blob/public/Telegraph/TGModernConversationController.mm) find `_collectionView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation((CGFloat)M_PI);` and [Cell](https://github.com/peter-iakovlev/Telegram/blob/public/Telegraph/TGModernCollectionCell.m);
It's easy and solve other problems like insert new messages without jumping